# Python 3 - decode spectroscopy data (Base64, IEEE754)

Tags: python, base64, ieee-754

I'm a chemist and working with spectroscopic data that was stored as a list (501 pairs of X,Y data) of Base64-encoded floating point values according to IEEE754.

I tried to get an array of X, Y data to work with from the raw data but failed. Attached is the raw data of a spectrum.

May I please ask for your guidance/help on this topic? I'm lost,
Chris

`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`

Comment: Do you need a converter in Python, or do you just need this one set of data converted?

Comment: Dear Eric,
I'm very happy to see your answer! I need to work with many datasets from a database. That's why I'd like to do the conversion using Python. I know very little about it - but nothing about other languages...

I will try to work with the information you supplied and report later today.

Comment: When I try to do this:base64.base64decode('0x00...')

Comment: When I try to do this:
base64.base64decode('0x00...') the error 'Incorrect padding' occurs. I guess that the beginning '0x' has to be removed (I found a discussion about this related to Java and Python complains about wrong padding if I leave it in).

The result of the above is:
b'\xd3M4\xd3M4...
'\x'  apparently devides the long text into smaller pieces like 'd3M4 d3M4'. This should be the hexadecimal part you talked about.

Is this procedure correct so far?

Comment: I tried something else:
Counted the characters of the long text that I posted: 16032 if '0x' is not considered. I divided that number by 1002 (501 pairs of x,y values must be present) = 16.
I then tried 'bytes.fromhex('0000000000807140')'
Eric told me the 'ordering' of the data.
Thus, I finally I tried:
'struct.unpack('<d', bytes.fromhex('0000000000807140'))[0]' and got '280.0', the first wavelength in nm I desire.
I will go from this point on and report later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data appears to be IEEE-754 basic 64-bit binary floating-point shown in little-endian hexadecimal.

I am not experienced enough with Python to write a converter easily, so I converted with C. The converted data is below. It looks like 501 values for X (or Y) followed by 501 values for Y (or X).

```
280
281
282
283
284
285
286
287
288
289
290
291
292
293
294
295
296
297
298
299
300
301
302
303
304
305
306
307
308
309
310
311
312
313
314
315
316
317
318
319
320
321
322
323
324
325
326
327
328
329
330
331
332
333
334
335
336
337
338
339
340
341
342
343
344
345
346
347
348
349
350
351
352
353
354
355
356
357
358
359
360
361
362
363
364
365
366
367
368
369
370
371
372
373
374
375
376
377
378
379
380
381
382
383
384
385
386
387
388
389
390
391
392
393
394
395
396
397
398
399
400
401
402
403
404
405
406
407
408
409
410
411
412
413
414
415
416
417
418
419
420
421
422
423
424
425
426
427
428
429
430
431
432
433
434
435
436
437
438
439
440
441
442
443
444
445
446
447
448
449
450
451
452
453
454
455
456
457
458
459
460
461
462
463
464
465
466
467
468
469
470
471
472
473
474
475
476
477
478
479
480
481
482
483
484
485
486
487
488
489
490
491
492
493
494
495
496
497
498
499
500
501
502
503
504
505
506
507
508
509
510
511
512
513
514
515
516
517
518
519
520
521
522
523
524
525
526
527
528
529
530
531
532
533
534
535
536
537
538
539
540
541
542
543
544
545
546
547
548
549
550
551
552
553
554
555
556
557
558
559
560
561
562
563
564
565
566
567
568
569
570
571
572
573
574
575
576
577
578
579
580
581
582
583
584
585
586
587
588
589
590
591
592
593
594
595
596
597
598
599
600
601
602
603
604
605
606
607
608
609
610
611
612
613
614
615
616
617
618
619
620
621
622
623
624
625
626
627
628
629
630
631
632
633
634
635
636
637
638
639
640
641
642
643
644
645
646
647
648
649
650
651
652
653
654
655
656
657
658
659
660
661
662
663
664
665
666
667
668
669
670
671
672
673
674
675
676
677
678
679
680
681
682
683
684
685
686
687
688
689
690
691
692
693
694
695
696
697
698
699
700
701
702
703
704
705
706
707
708
709
710
711
712
713
714
715
716
717
718
719
720
721
722
723
724
725
726
727
728
729
730
731
732
733
734
735
736
737
738
739
740
741
742
743
744
745
746
747
748
749
750
751
752
753
754
755
756
757
758
759
760
761
762
763
764
765
766
767
768
769
770
771
772
773
774
775
776
777
778
779
780
100.0651511420070534086335101164877414703369140625
100.13957804703790088751702569425106048583984375
100.1236937406871447819867171347141265869140625
100.0214682890987631935786339454352855682373046875
99.9744469904184143160819076001644134521484375
99.9923251725196422512453864328563213348388671875
100.0039509493090719161045853979885578155517578125
100.0064033131639433804593863897025585174560546875
100.0245382525192923139911727048456668853759765625
100.0393611093758323704605572856962680816650390625
100.0350211285674646433108136989176273345947265625
100.0201450066373780600770260207355022430419921875
100.00948059772207443529623560607433319091796875
100.0134029402622246607279521413147449493408203125
100.0333907457171989108246634714305400848388671875
100.062739923967995991915813647210597991943359375
100.097471426858561471817665733397006988525390625
100.0898091626175556712041725404560565948486328125
100.042169688825225648542982526123523712158203125
100.0285316291862187654260196723043918609619140625
100.0542106520156124815912335179746150970458984375
100.0634965037339014770623180083930492401123046875
100.04915794906065684699569828808307647705078125
100.0707187043640118417897610925137996673583984375
100.1014929373547346358463983051478862762451171875
100.0552223150108233085120446048676967620849609375
99.997484565242530152318067848682403564453125
100.019389105275962492669350467622280120849609375
100.0608435227355386132330750115215778350830078125
100.054712507515802144553163088858127593994140625
100.050141904213745647211908362805843353271484375
100.0692902663437280352809466421604156494140625
100.064077878201686644388246349990367889404296875
100.0283782298722456971518113277852535247802734375
100.018624618541167592411511577665805816650390625
100.0369317712395087482946109957993030548095703125
100.029922834780137463894789107143878936767578125
99.9754772528461188585424679331481456756591796875
99.94824630932777154157520271837711334228515625
99.996653658641690753938746638596057891845703125
100.05398850141995126250549219548702239990234375
100.06711916954014895964064635336399078369140625
100.0770859616790602331093396060168743133544921875
100.101126628519267569572548381984233856201171875
100.124194768973808322698459960520267486572265625
100.136584547682645052191219292581081390380859375
100.112924179832901927511557005345821380615234375
100.082033156360040493382257409393787384033203125
100.059733548229218058622791431844234466552734375
100.0762467144847818190100952051579952239990234375
100.114817097265103029712918214499950408935546875
100.0776895993700037479356979019939899444580078125
99.9997760982723349343359586782753467559814453125
100.0078943019934598623876809142529964447021484375
100.0967117634881589083306607790291309356689453125
100.13087462062912891269661486148834228515625
100.063526766889566488316631875932216644287109375
99.99212258138908282489865086972713470458984375
100.0027849740351797436233027838170528411865234375
100.068040657093064282889827154576778411865234375
100.134467999725899289842345751821994781494140625
100.166153059623951548928744159638881683349609375
100.129428966360563890702906064689159393310546875
100.074066129282385873011662624776363372802734375
100.047577693169813528584199957549571990966796875
100.0562993478715725359506905078887939453125
100.0412123662481036490135011263191699981689453125
100.010279668284084664264810271561145782470703125
100.0109994770969450428310665301978588104248046875
100.002870412533667376919765956699848175048828125
100.004202032182746506805415265262126922607421875
100.0542212272784325932661886326968669891357421875
100.0740509070095214383400161750614643096923828125
100.07440692289497974343248642981052398681640625
100.1025865467552335985601530410349369049072265625
100.08081062310651532243355177342891693115234375
100.0206537934144961354832048527896404266357421875
100.0339555056795717291606706567108631134033203125
100.100427852658953042919165454804897308349609375
100.1262307167416309994223411194980144500732421875
100.100098012499756805482320487499237060546875
100.0427707907807501896968460641801357269287109375
99.9932590416555768797479686327278614044189453125
99.9548137769725570933587732724845409393310546875
99.9522728355375562614426598884165287017822265625
99.987470202013327025269973091781139373779296875
100.023865694456929986699833534657955169677734375
100.0145534701357092899343115277588367462158203125
99.9844476054285706823065993376076221466064453125
100.0248528335507529618553235195577144622802734375
100.10420064602811862641829065978527069091796875
100.118396793276957623675116337835788726806640625
100.071721389697160020659794099628925323486328125
100.02513152058867262894636951386928558349609375
100.0087725365609543359823874197900295257568359375
99.98757594588340680274995975196361541748046875
99.961962951982059166766703128814697265625
99.938261690451980712168733589351177215576171875
99.9971275340451626334470347501337528228759765625
100.06871939476286570425145328044891357421875
100.0228170437528234515411895699799060821533203125
99.9507570147975030749876168556511402130126953125
99.976371615204215004268917255103588104248046875
100.0001278285393482292420230805873870849609375
99.94898601060305054488708265125751495361328125
99.945661414209808981468086130917072296142578125
100.02453000558995199753553606569766998291015625
100.06642177881275301842833869159221649169921875
100.0496799109486119050416164100170135498046875
100.0424399556094243735060445033013820648193359375
100.0386251191020932083119987510144710540771484375
100.041150420153797995226341299712657928466796875
100.03359151286571204764186404645442962646484375
100.0342180089054409108939580619335174560546875
100.0137612307054695293118129484355449676513671875
99.966001352845381688894121907651424407958984375
99.9015825981283143164546345360577106475830078125
99.84785305144350786576978862285614013671875
99.8783214302314235055746394209563732147216796875
99.9604015781452517330762930214405059814453125
100.0135020032093535746753332205116748809814453125
100.0672268556372301873125252313911914825439453125
100.1258797503546560392351238988339900970458984375
100.1250495490572092194270226173102855682373046875
100.0697978040830236068359226919710636138916015625
100.0268892665721267576373065821826457977294921875
100.0134132082181537271026172675192356109619140625
100.02487655410226352614699862897396087646484375
100.0538584425471100303184357471764087677001953125
100.063944727541382917479495517909526824951171875
100.0443982007104324338797596283257007598876953125
100.06426728388686342441360466182231903076171875
100.1350432224052298124661319889128208160400390625
100.1307541536857712571872980333864688873291015625
100.0471538065583985144257894717156887054443359375
100.0077270470819570391540764831006526947021484375
100.0211324831371939581003971397876739501953125
100.0263532822682321921092807315289974212646484375
100.016585719104256213540793396532535552978515625
100.017439222447279689731658436357975006103515625
100.021046930318874501608661375939846038818359375
100.02331054898428419619449414312839508056640625
100.029053661666921470896340906620025634765625
100.04229531972777067494462244212627410888671875
100.04624197491085624278639443218708038330078125
100.0392239260699653868869063444435596466064453125
100.050315882739056405625888146460056304931640625
100.0567339554514916244443156756460666656494140625
100.0352618983654195972121669910848140716552734375
100.0289737735160287002145196311175823211669921875
100.038321250518009719598921947181224822998046875
100.02490854296530642386642284691333770751953125
99.99096709417352712989668361842632293701171875
99.9690503182581124974603881128132343292236328125
99.991570696665604600639198906719684600830078125
100.03832291887914607286802493035793304443359375
100.052155556782594203468761406838893890380859375
100.036743675828773803004878573119640350341796875
99.99152794899470109157846309244632720947265625
99.9843216496498001788495457731187343597412109375
100.0170982309832794499016017653048038482666015625
100.022327961958893638438894413411617279052734375
99.998380136364659165337798185646533966064453125
99.9610993132808260952515411190688610076904296875
99.9664840907736476083300658501684665679931640625
100.00205016388321155318408273160457611083984375
100.012888473796152766226441599428653717041015625
99.991604959025920607018633745610713958740234375
99.986095977218838015687651932239532470703125
100.0107720907422077516457648016512393951416015625
100.0268072165676045415239059366285800933837890625
100.0265168202997898561079637147486209869384765625
100.0304142174712751511833630502223968505859375
100.0380334115208142975461669266223907470703125
100.0218835621564181792564340867102146148681640625
99.985206923996912564689409919083118438720703125
99.9739315044275969057707698084414005279541015625
99.98105852840899387956596910953521728515625
99.969878777757230636780150234699249267578125
99.9452532816526542092105955816805362701416015625
99.9861470157467238095705397427082061767578125
100.0297288716514430007009650580585002899169921875
100.0259799615179616694149444811046123504638671875
100.0378975584280425437100348062813282012939453125
100.074260674600367337916395626962184906005859375
100.0638512274035605287281214259564876556396484375
100.019626891361696152671356685459613800048828125
100.0163473685410195912481867708265781402587890625
100.0514358668363996685002348385751247406005859375
100.0597817134081850554139236919581890106201171875
100.03116228311301938447286374866962432861328125
99.9696700839475198563377489335834980010986328125
99.8934668794350528742143069393932819366455078125
99.8676653269720162597877788357436656951904296875
99.884589399368678641621954739093780517578125
99.924934949068443756914348341524600982666015625
99.9904933098211330388949136249721050262451171875
100.0610378606795478617641492746770381927490234375
100.089312107420511210875702090561389923095703125
100.0964476589655447469340288080275058746337890625
100.0557514831237995167612098157405853271484375
99.991409841998716956368298269808292388916015625
99.9984595453001219311772729270160198211669921875
100.0416698934413943788968026638031005859375
100.051652109870843787575722672045230865478515625
100.033551313073303390410728752613067626953125
100.03544103182224489501095376908779144287109375
100.049421243300230344175361096858978271484375
100.045290465728299977854476310312747955322265625
100.0275883666428313745200284756720066070556640625
100.0184103696508230996187194250524044036865234375
100.021875147722340670952689833939075469970703125
100.02804275957424806620110757648944854736328125
100.0216914692214373872047872282564640045166015625
100.04084047274687918616109527647495269775390625
100.088302695364433247959823347628116607666015625
100.1639875289863397256340249441564083099365234375
100.118089042289255985451745800673961639404296875
100.0058996169324672109723906032741069793701171875
100.01600726776752026125905103981494903564453125
100.065881179186504823519499041140079498291015625
100.0430438014690679437990183942019939422607421875
99.9648796479037997642080881632864475250244140625
99.975598087840609196064178831875324249267578125
100.044079447186646802947507239878177642822265625
100.0418997420351701066465466283261775970458984375
99.98976684294137839970062486827373504638671875
99.96906102201018029518309049308300018310546875
99.9658314706747006539444555528461933135986328125
99.979240336047354276161058805882930755615234375
100.0283191635082715720272972248494625091552734375
100.082433766032210087359999306499958038330078125
100.1155367198896186664569540880620479583740234375
100.0818956080290291765777510590851306915283203125
99.984633600835678635121439583599567413330078125
99.9379289791978493440183228813111782073974609375
99.9736411293907849540119059383869171142578125
100.028540112024842301252647303044795989990234375
100.03656409622317369212396442890167236328125
100.004612964145593423381797038018703460693359375
100.0461138259634168434786261059343814849853515625
100.134546452736202581945690326392650604248046875
100.0949085753459968373135779984295368194580078125
99.950677527908936781386728398501873016357421875
99.9513509659069967483446816913783550262451171875
100.083988919481953416834585368633270263671875
100.0955398687036250748860766179859638214111328125
99.9884157453349047273150063119828701019287109375
99.95137709492200883687473833560943603515625
99.994749051304978593179839663207530975341796875
100.0166115256366765606799162924289703369140625
100.0024904118933051222484209574759006500244140625
100.00005852918303617116180248558521270751953125
100.0118783484143563100587925873696804046630859375
100.0307282299476128173409961163997650146484375
100.0160564958891171727373148314654827117919921875
99.9636336507001175277764559723436832427978515625
99.9623808691247859314898960292339324951171875
100.00372536972417947254143655300140380859375
100.0216146820599902866888442076742649078369140625
100.0156766425895256134026567451655864715576171875
100.026318781529454327028361149132251739501953125
100.051746760203712938164244405925273895263671875
100.0662379289816641403376706875860691070556640625
100.0682953298942692299533518962562084197998046875
100.0739097413264602209892473183572292327880859375
100.08581455341374066847492940723896026611328125
100.0608957896331929759980994276702404022216796875
99.9898109146580509332125075161457061767578125
99.9521979536526714582578279078006744384765625
99.968632736383966630455688573420047760009765625
100.008437122938317997977719642221927642822265625
100.0672100353427822483354248106479644775390625
100.08740195743558842877973802387714385986328125
100.0624565534972134628333151340484619140625
99.9947511632868923925343551672995090484619140625
99.937292633296038957269047386944293975830078125
99.891568628138287522233440540730953216552734375
99.8624056543120133255797554738819599151611328125
99.859118710684384723208495415747165679931640625
99.9349461855837120083378977142274379730224609375
100.0709837888388307192144566215574741363525390625
100.1067646698179629538572044111788272857666015625
100.046193515136366158913006074726581573486328125
99.98355846496900767306215129792690277099609375
99.9151553972383368318332941271364688873291015625
99.89624792821524579267133958637714385986328125
99.9493111823992848030684399418532848358154296875
99.98608176923107748734764754772186279296875
99.9801563879702683834693743847310543060302734375
99.985428467989322598441503942012786865234375
100.0249339815160141142769134603440761566162109375
100.01966841087465809323475696146488189697265625
99.969276380967215800410485826432704925537109375
99.8953398459106978179988800548017024993896484375
99.9555451848556089089470333419740200042724609375
100.1027341393819796167008462361991405487060546875
100.124537178204349174848175607621669769287109375
100.0449095286769960466699558310210704803466796875
99.9940939247723150629099109210073947906494140625
99.9653798192203311145931365899741649627685546875
99.990319353316891692884382791817188262939453125
100.0755925858066888167741126380860805511474609375
100.0664460710340364357762155123054981231689453125
99.9535981748814066349950735457241535186767578125
99.880041173768546514111221767961978912353515625
99.8564455912262900483256089501082897186279296875
99.91550571181056739078485406935214996337890625
100.0698421951832841614304925315082073211669921875
100.13742886432868317569955252110958099365234375
100.075494993388730335936998017132282257080078125
100.0341216115006517384244943968951702117919921875
100.04576377276129051097086630761623382568359375
100.0654367141467133706100867129862308502197265625
100.0885807403675329396719462238252162933349609375
100.1112212232493305918978876434266567230224609375
100.125714104466936760218231938779354095458984375
100.1246502253050181252547190524637699127197265625
100.10854697335815899350563995540142059326171875
100.081863397851947183880838565528392791748046875
100.020566679405447985118371434509754180908203125
99.9354137037535537047006073407828807830810546875
99.98397259110191725994809530675411224365234375
100.1519273267599459131815820001065731048583984375
100.1272525960946921941285836510360240936279296875
99.91166748382676132678170688450336456298828125
99.8748844651859002397031872533261775970458984375
100.0422399094290000221008085645735263824462890625
100.1037583583493102423744858242571353912353515625
100.0117610726506001128655043430626392364501953125
99.9937244989476567980091203935444355010986328125
100.107058718240523376152850687503814697265625
100.1476219902132243078085593879222869873046875
100.0396632450218277199383010156452655792236328125
99.9200607083717642353803967125713825225830078125
99.8153541625817553040178609080612659454345703125
99.8754462782883223326280131004750728607177734375
99.98507426037571121923974715173244476318359375
100.042298528577447314091841690242290496826171875
100.17309506497957727333414368331432342529296875
100.32719129730827489765943028032779693603515625
100.360233549828791410618578083813190460205078125
100.266872062516057440006989054381847381591796875
100.178844120116792737462674267590045928955078125
100.115694327609588754057767800986766815185546875
100.055350137896283513327944092452526092529296875
99.999140580524681354290805757045745849609375
100.009187284591689603985287249088287353515625
100.0855018600232568815044942311942577362060546875
100.105037236275705936350277625024318695068359375
100.066969036955669025701354257762432098388671875
100.0495723903635649776333593763411045074462890625
100.02713217598329720203764736652374267578125
100.04194759974353701181826181709766387939453125
100.162825414923844391523743979632854461669921875
100.1797312676168729694836656562983989715576171875
100.062410297028719696754706092178821563720703125
99.8285151755835471476530074141919612884521484375
99.8414541316773949120033648796379566192626953125
100.0248124475498769925252418033778667449951171875
100.2158401022440017413828172720968723297119140625
100.3146692225588907376732095144689083099365234375
100.2224237803358590781499515287578105926513671875
100.118270008616974564574775286018848419189453125
100.0655794793826345312481862492859363555908203125
100.0633392303213184959531645290553569793701171875
99.9554414999013687292972463183104991912841796875
99.8084400240407916271578869782388210296630859375
99.85322603916500838749925605952739715576171875
100.032338124651914768037386238574981689453125
99.963689005514339669389300979673862457275390625
99.6998840717295706781442277133464813232421875
99.7883737560768366847696597687900066375732421875
100.1924148279095021507600904442369937896728515625
100.2571637568399722795220441184937953948974609375
99.9754448147738230545655824244022369384765625
99.9167019677889101103573921136558055877685546875
100.1027075937517309967006440274417400360107421875
100.182205901401943037853925488889217376708984375
100.14558945525556055144988931715488433837890625
100.0900064119109487137393443845212459564208984375
100.0250270352438093368618865497410297393798828125
99.909949577205480863995035178959369659423828125
99.9171215333131641500585828907787799835205078125
99.9903837270596085318175028078258037567138671875
99.9304872847016127934693940915167331695556640625
99.9091210731919687759727821685373783111572265625
100.1263644204097573719991487450897693634033203125
100.224177374287904740413068793714046478271484375
99.93895741693495438084937632083892822265625
99.7675970252667951854164130054414272308349609375
99.8392526734424592405048315413296222686767578125
100.100207828065123294436489231884479522705078125
100.2763150170377031145108048804104328155517578125
100.4750778920937364091514609754085540771484375
100.4730605471329880629127728752791881561279296875
100.1715728487554457615260616876184940338134765625
100.0702181922118683132794103585183620452880859375
100.2672542837313613972582970745861530303955078125
100.2808437430378916133122402243316173553466796875
100.03564505073660484413267113268375396728515625
99.7884155709254940802566125057637691497802734375
99.5994448783435331051805405877530574798583984375
99.6762537864467930148748564533889293670654296875
100.041386091709540551164536736905574798583984375
100.25167953377194862696342170238494873046875
100.217387867003452583958278410136699676513671875
100.0334343104056102902177372016012668609619140625
99.7327336441743028672135551460087299346923828125
99.70854414054161907188245095312595367431640625
100.0549036807477705224300734698772430419921875
100.2473263479500218409157241694629192352294921875
100.11721448213933172155520878732204437255859375
99.990665950901103542491910047829151153564453125
99.9179217357013698119772016070783138275146484375
99.7615996962114905954877031035721302032470703125
99.549218481071449105002102442085742950439453125
99.5029772201969393563558696769177913665771484375
99.801615260393674589067813940346240997314453125
100.204789019906485236788284964859485626220703125
100.33655462886741815964342094957828521728515625
100.1701243459351502451681881211698055267333984375
99.88183455197241755740833468735218048095703125
99.7718850749182166737227817066013813018798828125
99.8744698102779011605889536440372467041015625
100.1388528017137531378466519527137279510498046875
100.0455600678224783450787072069942951202392578125
99.7497466686670435365158482454717159271240234375
99.8516993268806771766321617178618907928466796875
100.242929984258438480537733994424343109130859375
100.468127835287333482483518309891223907470703125
100.522852609983232241575024090707302093505859375
100.4412227484830140156191191636025905609130859375
100.23523824126078807239537127315998077392578125
100.1170475687707579481866559945046901702880859375
100.1107519100770133491096203215420246124267578125
100.0714145174189440012924023903906345367431640625
100.0193854618437256931429146789014339447021484375
100.0446638999243305079289712011814117431640625
100.1115070957248889271795633248984813690185546875
100.07875085712925056213862262666225433349609375
100.058608789114572346079512499272823333740234375
99.919001187603072366982814855873584747314453125
99.659309108048290681836078874766826629638671875
99.5704217066983829909077030606567859649658203125
99.586205853565644474656437523663043975830078125
99.64128551020127133597270585596561431884765625
99.84433683275028670323081314563751220703125
100.0099776053518638718742295168340206146240234375
99.9670113279745606860160478390753269195556640625
99.8468472195449834316605119965970516204833984375
99.903161779908288053775322623550891876220703125
100.211603386747839294912409968674182891845703125
100.487492615493437142504262737929821014404296875
100.5055801181483587924958555959165096282958984375
100.370293220767734965193085372447967529296875
100.2000213236938321870184154249727725982666015625
100.04687845757615605180035345256328582763671875
100.00091491094718776366789825260639190673828125
100.1375739265728128657428896985948085784912109375
100.424825543748880818384350277483463287353515625
100.56676469873133328292169608175754547119140625
100.24553513584208985776058398187160491943359375
99.8168304432850135299304383806884288787841796875
99.9534854463446293948436505161225795745849609375
100.4114281571791167380069964565336704254150390625
100.3977288844160540293160011060535907745361328125
100.1535149075679811403460917063057422637939453125
99.804955285662828146087122149765491485595703125
99.885111636591915384997264482080936431884765625
100.232638251505392190665588714182376861572265625
100.3687135495249691530261770822107791900634765625
100.229960227917899828753434121608734130859375
99.9002130896684690242182114161550998687744140625
99.5977409140039782187159289605915546417236328125
99.7333010777403927704654051922261714935302734375
100.08461620079782505854382179677486419677734375
100.0340877448094261126243509352207183837890625
99.7709845390721596913863322697579860687255859375
99.921722073431936905762995593249797821044921875
100.320777050345412817478063516318798065185546875
100.2757734427847964298052829690277576446533203125
99.88708896347679910832084715366363525390625
99.8712974105200004260041168890893459320068359375
100.341863176274642910357215441763401031494140625
100.4455221618055560384163982234895229339599609375
99.9709632933217307027007336728274822235107421875
99.897113540611400139823672361671924591064453125
100.455685791317165467262384481728076934814453125
100.786692971736783874803222715854644775390625
100.4785709305697736226647975854575634002685546875
100.0440024597821349061632645316421985626220703125
100.071789488042924176625092513859272003173828125
100.3095087818971506976595264859497547149658203125
100.2514562278748968537911423482000827789306640625
100.1133804513355158860576921142637729644775390625
100.071709334947428260420565493404865264892578125
100.0171466250988459023574250750243663787841796875
100.180611747212225282055442221462726593017578125
100.3664748747335835332705755718052387237548828125
100.29306951113193235869402997195720672607421875
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks so much for your help. I found a way to get the data into an array I'm used to wirk with.
Chris

```
import numpy
import struct

s = 'String without the 0x part'
n = 16
a = [s[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(s), n)]
b = [struct.unpack('<d', bytes.fromhex(a[i]))[0] for i in range(0, len(a), 1)]

c = np.asarray(b)
d = c[0:int(len(c)*0.5)]
e = c[int(len(c)*0.5):int(len(c))]
f = np.hstack((d, e))
plt.plot(d, e)
```